# I'm trying to find the last column with data in each row and return the column name to the data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to get the column name the value from ffill is from.

I've searched google and stack overflow and haven't found a way to accomplish this.

This is the ffill code:
    df["LAST_PUNCH"] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]

This is my dataframe:

```
SHIFT     IN     OUT    IN_1    
DA6-0730  07:30  12:35  13:05      
DB0-ACOM  08:18  12:30             
DC4-0730  07:30  12:39  13:09     
DC4-0730  07:30  12:34  13:04
```

This is my dataframe after using ffill:

```
SHIFT     IN     OUT    IN_1   LAST_PUNCH
DA6-0730  07:30  12:35  13:05  13:05
DB0-ACOM  08:18  12:30         12:30
DC4-0730  07:30  12:39  13:09  13:09
DC4-0730  07:30  12:34  13:04  13:04
```

I would like to get the column name where the ffill value came from and 
append to the end of the ffill value:

```
SHIFT     IN     OUT    IN_1   LAST_PUNCH
DA6-0730  07:30  12:35  13:05  13:05_IN_1
DB0-ACOM  08:18  12:30         12:30_OUT
DC4-0730  07:30  12:39  13:09  13:09_IN_1
DC4-0730  07:30  12:34  13:04  13:04_IN_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummm this is a little bit tricky

```
(df+'_'+pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df.columns.values,df.columns.values)),index=df.index)).\
    reindex(columns=df.columns).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]
Out[360]: 
0    13:05_IN_1
1     12:30_OUT
2    13:09_IN_1
3    13:04_IN_1
Name: IN_1, dtype: object
```

Or using `idxmax` with reversed order of columns

```
df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]+'_'+df[df.columns[::-1]].notnull().idxmax(1)
Out[375]: 
0    13:05_IN_1
1     12:30_OUT
2    13:09_IN_1
3    13:04_IN_1
dtype: object
```

Comment: I'm curious will the idxmax  method work correctly after 00:00 as the data is a time and not a datetime or am I not understanding?

Comment: @user3249641 idxmax will work for finding the first max value's index